# Ошибка HTTPS. Это страница содержит незащищенный контент

Tags: https

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток. 
Подскажите какую либо информацию. Подробности что это может быть и как можно обойти эту ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сообщение означает, что на данной странице размещен контент который не использует шифрование и/или находится по другому адресу. 
Это может быть что угодно. Вы можете загружать на странице картинки с другого домена, использовать API других сайтов без использования https и т.д.

Например на странице присутствует изображение, которое вы разместили на специальном статик сервере на другом домене и адрес у него http, а не https.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Да. Действительно используются видео файлы с http сайта. Возможно ли как либо обойти эту ошибку. Или с этим ничего не поделаешь?

Comment: @Ford, К сожалению нет, только перевести видео файлы на https. Возможно сайт с которого грузятся файлы поддерживает шифрование? Например youtube поддерживает оба варианта.